# cPanel SSL ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

Tags: mysql, ssl, centos, cpanel, whm

I'm trying to set up SSL for mysql on my WHM server. I've been following the [official cPanel documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+MySQL+SSL+Connections), but am having an issue with it. I've created all the certificates and keys, set the owner to mysql, and added the lines specified to the my.cnf file, but after restarting mysql and running the below command it gives this error:

```
root@euk-92874 [~]# mysql -e "show variables like '%ssl%';"
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

This is the my.cnf file (I've tried the paths with and without the ' quotes around them):

```
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
#[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
#!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
open_files_limit=10000
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0
max_user_connections=200
max_connections=500
interactive_timeout=300
wait_timeout=200
join_buffer_size = 128M
connect_timeout=300
#group_concat_max_len=2;
max-allowed-packet             = 32M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
### INNODB
#innodb_buffer_pool_size=1000M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_file_per_table=1
## You may want to tune the below depending on number of cores and disk sub
innodb_write_io_threads=4
#innodb_io_capacity=20000
#innodb_io_capacity_max=40000
innodb_doublewrite=1
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
## avoid statistics update when doing e.g show tables
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#REPLICATION SPECIFIC _ GENERAL
#server_id must be unique across all mysql servers participating in replication.

#OTHER THINGS, BUFFERS ETC
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 12M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
skip_name_resolve
table_cache = 750M
query_cache_limit = 30M
query_cache_size = 48M
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
memlock=0
sysdate_is_now=1
max_connections=2000
thread_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type = 2
table_open_cache=1024
lower_case_table_names=0
thread_concurrency = 4

max_allowed_packet=268435456

ssl
ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ssl-ca='/mysql_keys/ca-cert.pem'
ssl-cert='/mysql_keys/server-cert.pem'
ssl-key='/mysql_keys/server-key.pem'


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[client]
ssl
ssl-cert='/mysql_keys/client-cert.pem'
ssl-key='/mysql_keys/client-key.pem'

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M


 [mysqld_safe]
#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The certs and keys are in the folder:

```
root@euk-92265 [~]# ls -la /mysql_keys
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   2 mysql mysql 4096 May 11 09:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root  root  4096 May 11 09:35 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1472 May 11 08:54 ca-cert.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1679 May 11 08:53 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1346 May 11 08:57 client-cert.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1675 May 11 08:57 client-key.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1123 May 11 08:57 client-req.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1346 May 11 08:56 server-cert.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1675 May 11 08:56 server-key.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 mysql mysql 1155 May 11 08:56 server-req.pem
```

I would also provide a log but I'm not sure where to find it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are the ssl files really in the directory '/mysql_keys'. What permissions (include `ls -la /mysql_keys` by editing your question)?

Comment: Yes they're there - I've updated the question

Comment: Try looking at the mysql error log. `chmod go-r /mysql_keys/server*key.pem` somethings refuse to open publicly readable server keys. Could need selinux labels to read them correctly? unrelated.`default-storage-engine=MyISAM` looks like a mistake given you've got 1G buffer pools size.

Comment: Where is the mysql log file? I tried to find it but couldn't

Comment: probably journald on centos. `journalctl -u mariadb.service` or `mysql.service`

Comment: That command returned no entries for both of those

Comment: if centos7 maybe in /var/lib/mysql/{hostname}.err. Alternately look at the running mysqld and `lsof -p $(pidof mysqld)` and look where file descriptors 1,2 are pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being because both certificates were using the exact same details and were conflicting with each other.

Comment: Which certificates were using exact details? What details you needed to change to make it work?